# python 3.6.7 tkinter did not display Entry

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, grid, calculator, display

I'm running the following code on linux pycharm, on python 3.6.7 and the Entry() is not displayed . Please help me !! 
Code :

```
from tkinter import *

calculator = Tk()
calculator.title("Calculator")
calculator.resizable(0, 0)

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.display = Entry(self, font=("Helvetica", 16), relief=RAISED, justify=RIGHT)
        self.display.insert(0, "default value")
        self.display.grid(row=0, column=0)



app = Application(calculator).grid
calculator.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       —-Syntax Error—-
```

app = Application(calculator).grid    -> wrong
app = Application(calculator).grid()  -> right

Comment: You should separate `.grid()` into another statement if you want to use `app` variable later as your solution is assigned the result of `.grid()` to variable `app` which is always `None`.  Otherwise, remove `app = `.